# Which label did the user last touch and how to remove it from the view

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I want to know how to know which label the user last touched and how to remove that specific label from the view.  I know how to change the properties for all labels, but I don't know how to find out which one was last selected.

This is how I add a label to the view.

```
myNewLabel.text =textField.text;
numberOfLabels++;
myNewLabel.tag=numberOfLabels;
[self.view addSubview:myNewLabel];
[shirtBackgroundView addSubview:myNewLabel];
[myNewLabel addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
[myNewLabel addGestureRecognizer:rotateGestureRecognizer];
[myNewLabel addGestureRecognizer:PinchGestureRecognizer];
myNewLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
myNewLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
[arrayForLabels addObject:myNewLabel];
```

Here is how I change the color of all labels.

```
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLabels;i++)
    {
        UILabel *tempLabel = [arrayForLabels objectAtIndex:i];
        tempLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }



 -(void)labelMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];



    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
        CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
        CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 200;
        NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

        float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult; // Increase for more of a slide
        CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
        finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), self.view.bounds.size.width);
        finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), self.view.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
        } completion:nil];


    }

}
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detect `UIlabels` to capture taps:

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 UIGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecieved:)]; 
[label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

//repeat for each additional label
when you touched

```
-(void) tapRecieved:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap{  
      currentLabel = (UILabel *) tap.view;
        [currentLabel removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a property in .h class as UILabel *lastSelectedLabel; and in your recognizer

```
-(void)labelMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
          if(lastSelectedLabel!=nil){
                [lastSelectedLabel removeFromSuperview];
                lastSelectedLabel=recognizer.view;

          }else
              lastSelectedLabel=recognizer.view;
}
```

I think above should work..

Thanks.